# Is it common to die at work?

Tags: the-sims-3

I downloaded *The Sims 3* for my Android phone, and I've played through almost 2 Sim weeks with my character. My sim works Monday–Friday, and without fail, he will die every other day at work. If he survived work yesterday, he will die today. Period. He's been killed by everything from escaped research monkeys to choking on a pretzel.

Death isn't such a big deal. I just go back to the main screen, select my character, and I'm back. The biggest frustration is that I don't get paid on the days that I die, which means I'm only collecting about half of the Simoleons that I earn. This makes progress in the game very slow, to the point that I'm about ready to give up.

So my question is: can I do something to avoid dying at work, or is it random? If it's random, is it supposed to happen this often, or am I insanely unlucky?

Comment: This is the most depressing question ever...poor sims.

Comment: I know every day I spend at my 9-5 kills me a little bit on the inside.

Comment: @edsobo You only are at work from 9 to 5, so you've got nothing to complain about.

Comment: gaming.stackexchange.com: Best. Question titles. Ever.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [only thing](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960206-the-sims-3/49828220) I can find about this seems to indicate that it's a problem with your Sim running out (or, ew, overflowing) of something important stat-wise during the workday.

Apparently your Sim doesn't think to stop to eat lunch or go to the bathroom during the day, so you've got to make sure they eat a big breakfast and take a potty break in the morning hours, lest they collapse at work from an overeager bladder when you're not there to tell them to pee.

Try seeing if you can't get them through the day if they head off to work with all their "needs" properly met.

Comment: Your answer here also answered my question, "Do I ever want to play The Sims 3 on Android?" Apparently not.

Comment: It seems to me that perhaps jobs in The Sims are modeled after the jobs [EA employees](http://ea-spouse.livejournal.com/274.html) have.

Comment: Well my sim has stopped dying at work. I'm not sure if it's because I got a promotion, which moved me past a glitch in the game, or if it's because I've been paying closer attention to his vitals in the morning before work. Either way, this seems like a reasonable answer, so I'm accepting it.